# Does cudaMalloc() initialize the array to 0?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, malloc, memset

Or do I need to perform cudaMemset() if I want to make sure the array contains all 0? I can't find it in the documentation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`cudaMalloc` documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) says:

> Allocates `size` bytes of linear memory on the device and returns in `*devPtr` a pointer to the allocated memory. The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. **The memory is not cleared.**

So, you will need `cudaMemset` to initialize the memory.